# JavaNullPointerException/Layout Error when working with lists and ListView on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, android-widget

Hey, I'm trying to implement a ListView on Android, which will print the data retrieved from the SQLite Database. So I want to retrieve a lot of columns from the table and add this to a list, so I will print this list as a ListView.

For this I created a method that will select all the columns from the table in a separate class, and I will print the ListView in a ListActivity.

I want to retrieve 6 columns of the table, which is represented by the ids 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9.

But it shows a lot of errors:

```
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1418)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1248)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-24 19:19:04.066: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code of the method that select the data.

```
public List<String> selectAll() {

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list4 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list5 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list6 = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null,
            "duration desc");

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            list1.add(cursor.getString(2));
            list2.add(cursor.getString(4));
            list3.add(cursor.getString(5));
            list4.add(cursor.getString(6));
            list5.add(cursor.getString(7));
            list6.add(cursor.getString(9));

            list1.addAll(list2);
            list1.addAll(list3);
            list1.addAll(list4);
            list1.addAll(list5);
            list1.addAll(list6);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        Log.i(TAG, "After cursor.moveToNext()");
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "Before selectAll returnment");
    return list1;
}
```

And here is the code of the ListActivity class:

```
public class RatedCalls extends ListActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "RatedCallsActivity";
private CallDataHelper cdh;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(RatedCalls.this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "calling from onCreate()");

    cdh = new CallDataHelper(this);

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "--->>> before calling the service");
    startService(new Intent(this, RatedCallsService.class));
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Service called.");
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "--->>> after calling the service");
    fillList();

}

public void fillList() {

    List<String> ratedCalls = this.cdh.selectAll();

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem,
            ratedCalls));

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in the database if the column value was empty, the cursor returned null, so, that was the JavaNullPointerException. So If there was no contact name to insert in the database, I inserted an empty string. That works!

Answer (score 0):

Null pointer exception means something isn't initialized correctly. I've been able to decipher from the error log that it seems it's where a list is created somewhere, but I'm only seeing generic android classes, nothing from within your code. Not sure if this is going to help, but it looks like there's a part of the error stack missing, it could be quite helpful, so...

Comment: The code I've posted is the full code. I've tested the selectAll() method only gettin the id 0, like this: list1.add(cursor.getString(0)) and it worked fine. But after I added the getString(2), getString(4), ... and the addAll() to list1, it didn't worked. I think the error is because I tried to get a lot of columns at the same time. I dont know if I did the right way, but I think is it. If you have any solution for this pleas, post it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your NPE is here

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem, ratedCalls));
```

At least that's my guess from the logcat. Is R.layout.listitem null?

Why are you using just an ArrayAdapter. You should probably subclass `CursorAdapter`. It sounds like you want something more complicated than just an ArrayAdapter can give you.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your query. You read data that is not used. I don't know how many rows and columns do exist but you might see a small performance increase then.

Regards
hjw